# How to mock an authentication decorator with Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, pylons

I am going to mock an authentication decorator with Pytest. The framework is Pylons.
Can you please let me know if you have any experience?
Please help me! It's very important to me.

api.py

```python
@validate_and_configure_for_network
def ping(self):
    data = {
        "status": 200,
        "message": "OK"
    }
    return self.json_response(http_status=200, full_response=data)
```

conftest.py

```python
@pytest.fixture
def app(mocker):
    mocker.patch("ss.core.util.apiutil.validate_and_configure_for_network", return_value=True)
    app = create_app()
    return app
```

test_api.py

```python
class TestPing():
    def test_ping(self):
        var = NewApiController()
        ...
```